# Can't access azure storage blob via url even though authenticated

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage

I have a nodejs application using the express framework. The user must sign in via Oauth2 protocol against their MS Azure Active Directory credentials. This is done using the [passport-azure-ad-oauth2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-azure-ad-oauth2) npm package

I have successfully got the application working so that I can upload files in blob form to an azure storage container. The container access level is set to private. I have assigned user roles for the container so that certain users within the AD have 'reader and data access'. So my understanding is that when these users are authenticated via Oauth2, they should be able to access the files when retrieving the file's URL. However, after authentication, I am not able to access the files. I get the following error.

`ResourceNotFound`
The specified resource does not exist. RequestId:6341ef80-f01e-0011-6442-08f7c2000000 Time:2021-02-21T11:14:26.3475641Z

I have also followed the steps to grant the application permissions to azure storage [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app?tabs=dotnet)

What do I need to do so that authenticated users can go to the specific url for each blob and get access? Do I need to pass a token in the request? If so, how do you do this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The 404 error(*The specified resource does not exist*) is always related to your request URL, but not the access token.

For example to [get blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob), you need to use **GET** Method, and some of the Request Headers are required.

```
GET https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob
headers:  
     Authorization: Bear <access-token>
     x-ms-version: 2020-04-08
     x-ms-date: Fri, 26 Jun 2015 23:39:12 GMT
```

Get access token by application permission without user:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id={client_id}
&client_secret={client_secret}
&scope=http://storage.azure.com/.default  // change to http://storage.azure.com/ for resource
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

Get access token by delegated permission with a signed-in user:

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id={client_id}
&response_type=token
&redirect_uri=https://localhost:44300/
&scope=https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation
&response_mode=fragment
&state=12345
&nonce=678910
```

**Note:** Navigate to your storage account -> Access Control (IAM) -> Add role assignment -> select `Storage Blob Data XXX` role and your login account. I add Storage Blob Data Contributor in my side, it might take up to 5 minutes to propagate the RBAC rule.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Apologies as I am still learning. At what stage do I get the access token, immediately after logging in? Or do I request an access token each time I want to download a file via the URL? How do I structure the app so that the access token is always available after logging in so that any file can be downloaded so long as the user has authenticated?

Comment: Update - i have managed to get the access token using postman. However when I attempt to use the GET request to get the desired resource, i am getting a 403: not authorised response

Comment: You could get access token after logging in, see my second method using the [implicit flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow). But the access token will expire after one hour, you need to get it again. About 403 error, please see **Note** in my reply and you need to add storage API permission in your application.

Comment: Thank you for your help... so I have managed to get a 200 response in postman by replicating your 'delegated response with signed in user' code up above. But I am just wondering where the access token is? I just get set-cookie headers buid, fpc= etc... thanks again for your help

Comment: Access token is not stored automatically. If you use MSAL.js, you could store it in the token cache, sample [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-node-samples/standalone-samples/silent-flow).

Comment: Hi Pamela thank you for your help on this. Apologies for late reply I had to postpone work but am back now. I have a react front end app where the user signs in to the app using @azure/msal-browser. This seems to return a token and is stored in the cache. Can I use this token (token 1) to access the blob? Or do I need to get a different access token (token 2) using, say, your third code snippet above (get token delegated user)? If so, does the token received after initial login (token 1) need to be sent in the request to acquire token 2? Hope this makes sense